# Is it worth it creating "categories" for an SO-type site, or are tags the replacement?

Tags: database-design, postgresql

I have a posts table for my reddit-clone site and I'm wondering whether I should make categories per posts or just categorize by tags like SO has it. It seems like tags pretty much are a replacement for categories, but is there something I'm just overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are essentially ad-hoc categories with a one-to-many relationship.

I would go for tags.

Comment: Or to put it differently: if you allow more than one category for a post, then they are essentially tags.

Comment: Yeah, but where's the nerdy fun in describing that?

Answer (score 2):

On a reddit/SO-style site, I would go for tags. They are easy to grasp, quick to understand and to search.

It can be different where category trees really play an important role, e.g. when sorting by area of business in a business directory.

Comment: I agree with this description. I'd add that tags as they're used now tend to be flat and keyword-like. The limits of that can be seen with the Google search engine.